# JQuery Handling events when elements are being generated at run time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, loops

**Disclaimer: I'm new to JQuery**

I don't know how to title this question but first my code is below

```
$(document).on("click" ,'[id^="picChangeAddress"]', function() {
    $('div[id^="divAddressSet"]').toggle();
});
```

Please not that I have the same numbers of div's and checkboexes, each name format is same also such as checkboxes `picChangeAddress1, picChangeAddress2` and so on, and div's `divAddressSet1, divAddressSet2` and so on.

I've used the above code because these id's are being generated at run time. There are few things i need to ask first when i click on one checkbox all it effects every div `div[id^="divAddressSet"]` on the page and they all toggled when i click on any any of `[id^="picChangeAddress"]` checkbox. I would like you to help me on how to only show or hide only one div at a time.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract number from ID, then you can use ID selector to hide the div

```
$(document).on("click" ,'[id^="picChangeAddress"]', function() {
    var num = parseInt(this.id.match(/\d+/)[0],10); //Extract number
    $('#divAddressSet'+num).toggle();
});
```

Comment: @Jai, Yep but always be safe.

Comment: i usually don't use `.match()` but seems a great friend.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract the number from the ID and use that so that you target the correct selector:

```
$(document).on("click" ,'[id^="picChangeAddress"]', function() {
    $('div[id="divAddressSet'+this.id.substring(16)+'"]').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("click" ,'[id^="picChangeAddress"]', function() {
  var o = this.id.split('').pop();
  $("#divAddressSet"+o).toggle();
});
```